# What is the correct way to attribute a Stack Overflow answer in my code?

Tags: discussion, attribution, creative-commons

I understand that Stack Overflow answers are released under a Creative Commons license, and that I may use code from Stack Overflow answers (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript) one) in my work.

I want to give credit (as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18914/acknowledging-stack-overflow-users-in-my-application) mentions that I should) to the OP, how exactly should I do this? I was thinking of adding something along these lines above the relevant code:

```
// Code created with the help of Stack Overflow question
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript
// Question by Taylor:
// https://stackoverflow.com/users/460058/taylor
// Answer by Andrew Dunn:
// https://stackoverflow.com/users/451672/andrew-dunn
```

That's right, right?

Comment: See also [Attribution Required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) on the blog.

Comment: Thanks. Could you write that comment as an answer so I can close this question?

Comment: Well, does it really fully answer your question? Reading it myself, I could come up with many ways to interpret it...

Comment: This seems to me an excellent way to give attribution on your code

Comment: In lieu of other answers I will assume that my method of attribution is legit.

Comment: So it means, I have to give attribution to this question in my code if I'm planning to use this format?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Attribution Required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) blog post describes the attribution requirements in detail.

That said, if someone uses a small snippet of code that I post in a public forum for people to freely use, I don't particularly care that it be attributed back to me.  In fact, [some users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks) feel strongly enough about this that they put a disclaimer in their profile.

I view the CC:Wiki license as more of a protection against leeches that wholesale copy material from Stack Overflow and create their own websites with it, without giving credit to Stack Overflow or the original authors of the material.

Comment: I just add links to the SO questions or answers in my comments in my code.  Do I need to add a link to the author too?  I figured the author is on the post if you opened the link to the post.

Comment: Links have a tendency to rot.  I would imagine proper attribution includes not only a link, but "Stack Overflow" and the author's name.  At least, that's what the blog post says.

Comment: I usually just do `// From http://stackoverflow.com/a/381754/206403` in my code.  If the link to the question is gone, then a link to user wouldn't do too much.

Comment: (Hmmm, @Rocket, why linking [using your own user id](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink)? `;-)`)

Comment: @Arjan: I'm aware of that, but I don't really care if my user id is there.  What could happen? :-P